# How do you make Amarok skip video files when scanning your library?

Tags: audio, video, multimedia, amarok

I use Amarok as a music player; and it scans a bunch of folders of mine for files to include in its catalog. The thing is, some of these folders have video, rather than audio, files in them. These files have audio tracks - but I don't want the added to my catalog/library.

Can I do that somehow?

Note: I don't mind if I miss, say, files which are video clips of songs - I'm willing to tak some "false positives" in filtering videos out.